# How to create an interactive script in R to simplify/partly automate the data exploration part?

Tags: r

I would like to make an interactive menu in R - that interacts with me and then performs the selected tasks...I did some googling on interactive R / R user menu / etc. but nothing really helped.

I would like to present myself with the following interactive menu

1. clear all memory
2. load data
3. run regression model
4. run cluster model
   Make a choice please (1,2,3 or 4):

based on the selection it would ask additional input (eg. after option 2, load data it would give all the files present in the data/in directory under my project prepended with a number so I could choose which file to load by simply entering 1,2,3, etc.

I do prepare different datasets to run with my script (for different segments or scenarios) and would like to quickly switch between these. eg. business operational plan Oct'12, consumer budget plan, etc. Also I would not like to reload my data over and over again..

I was thinking of building something 'pseudocode' like

```
print the menu
ask user for input
ifelse(menuinput==1, source(script1.r),
      ifelse(menuinput== 2,source(script2.r),
      ifelse(menuinput==3,source(script3.r),NA)))
```

But I am not sure if there are easier ways to do this.

Thanks,

Geoffrey

Comment: have you looked at `package:miniGUI` , or the various Tcl interfaces?  `sos::???` is your friend here!

Comment: If you're going to be loading data on the fly you should consider serializing your data, this shortens loading time significantly. You can use saveRDS and readRDS for this purpose.

Comment: thanks. gonna check the xxRDS stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to design a customized menu I suggest you take a look Shiny by the folks at Rstudio.

I am using it to create an analysis and data-manipulation GUI for my students. It is a work in progress but should give you an idea of some of the things that are possible. Code and installation instructions linked below:

https://github.com/mostly-harmless/radyant

To see it in action on a server:

http://vnijs.rady.ucsd.edu:3838/marketing/

Comment: Great example of shiny usage... this was a bit of a cockpit I envisioned, but then old fashioned in text :) did not know that Shiny was already capable of this kind of interaction..... I am falling in love :)